# MySQL database updates to the round decimal

Tags: python, mysql, decimal, rounding, mysql-python

I am using Python 2.7 and MySQLdb. I am trying to update and set as the number the decimal I have set as data but what I get is an the closest integer. This is the code:

```
Value = 5
data = 5
data = data + 0.5
print(data)                       
x.execute(""" UPDATE Testing SET number = %s WHERE id = %s """, (data, Value))
conn.commit()
```

For example, if data = 5.5 and I try to update the database, I see in the table that the number is 6 when I want it to be 5.5. I have seen some others ask the same question but not in Python. Number is an INT. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `number` column in the `Testing` database table apparently has an integer data type. You can check the data type by querying `EXPLAIN Testing`. If it has an integer data type, the `number` value is  coerced to an integer before it stored in the table.

If you wish to store a decimal then you'll need to alter the table first:

```
ALTER TABLE `Testing` CHANGE `number` `number` DECIMAL(M,D)
```

where (per [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)):

- `M` is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
- `D` is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It
  has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than `M`.

---

For example, if we create a `Testing` table with `number` having an `INT(11)` data type:

```
import MySQLdb
import config

def show_table(cursor):
    select = 'SELECT * FROM Testing'
    cursor.execute(select)
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)

def create_table(cursor):
    sql = 'DROP TABLE Testing'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    sql = '''CREATE TABLE `Testing` (
             `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             `number` INT(11),
             PRIMARY KEY (id))'''
    cursor.execute(sql)

with MySQLdb.connect(host=config.HOST, user=config.USER, 
                     passwd=config.PASS, db='test') as cursor:

    create_table(cursor)
```

Suppose the table has a record with `number = 5`:

```
    insert = 'INSERT INTO Testing (number) VALUE (%s)'
    cursor.execute(insert, (5,))
    show_table(cursor)
    # (1L, 5L)
```

If we try to set the `number` to 5.5:

```
    update = 'UPDATE Testing SET number = %s where id = %s'
    cursor.execute(update, [5.5, 1])
```

instead the number is stored as 6:

```
    show_table(cursor)
    # (1L, 6L)
```

If we alter the data type of the `number` field to DECIMAL(8,2):

```
    alter = 'ALTER TABLE `Testing` CHANGE `number` `number` DECIMAL(8,2)'
    cursor.execute(alter)
```

then setting number to 5.5 stores `number` as a decimal:

```
    cursor.execute(update, [5.5, 1])
    show_table(cursor)
    # (1L, Decimal('5.50'))
```

---

Of course, alternatively, you could create a `Testing` table with a `number` field with DECIMAL data type from the beginning, and then floats would be stored as decimals from the start.

PS. It's not quite clear (to me) if you really want a `DECIMAL(M,D)` data type. If you use `DECIMAL(M,D)`, then querying the table will return `number`s which are `decimal.Decimal`s on the Python side. If you just want regular Python floats, then define `Testing` with a `number` field with data type `FLOAT` instead of `DECIMAL(M,D)`.